# How can I access the objects that are imported without knowing their name?

Tags: python, object, python-import

I am trying to make some code more extensible.  As part of the processing I expect to import some regular expressions pattern objects.  I do not want to know before the code executes during production how many there are - I will just use standard names for them.

```
start_0 = re.compile(r"some start pattern")
start_1 = re.compile(r"some other start pattern")
stop_0 = re.compile(r"some stop pattern")
stop_1 = re.compile(r"some other stop pattern")
 .
 .
 .
stop_n = re.compile(r"(some nth stop pattern")
```

I want to use all of the regex downstream based on the pattern of their name

So far all I have done is saved a list of regex and then imported them from the IDLE shell. That went fine and if I use the dir fuunction I can see them so I could call them by name but I want to call them using so generator process

```
for regex in my_regex_list.py:
    do_something with the regex
```

Is it possible to get the names without a lot of clutter?

Comment: Use a list, not separate variables.

Comment: I agree with Barmar, and would also like to remember MMNM: "Make it Modular, not Magical".

Comment: How obvious thanks @Barmar post it as an answer start_regex = [start_0, start_1, start_2, . . .]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the original regexps in separate variables, just put them in a list:

```
regex_list = [
    {start: r"some start pattern", end: r"some stop pattern"},
    {start: r"some other start pattern", end: r"some other end pattern"},
    ...
]

for regexes in regex_list:
    do someting with regexes.start and regexes.end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the right answer is: you shouldn't.

Any module should have a stable set of names which can be imported. The point is if you don't know the name you want to import, why expose it in the first place?

However you can create some kind of data structure you can import.

```
#mymodule.py
regex_list = [
    re.compile(r"some start pattern"),
    re.compile(r"some other start pattern"),
    ...
]

#main.py
from mymodule import regex_list
for regex in regex_list:
    ...
```

If you want to keep the names, then you can create a `dict` for it. If you want to keep both the name and the order you can use `collections.OrderedDict`.